# when deleting classical node struct after copying the node, must we worry about possible overwrites?

Tags: c++, algorithm, memory-management, data-structures, linked-list

https://leetcode.com/problems/delete-node-in-a-linked-list/description/

```
/**
 * Definition for singly-linked list.
 * struct ListNode {
 *     int val;
 *     ListNode *next;
 *     ListNode(int x) : val(x), next(NULL) {}
 * };
 */
```

Problem statement:
Given a linked list of at least size 2, you are given a pointer to one of the nodes (guaranteed not to be the tail).
Delete the node.

Linked list [1,2,3,4],
input: 2,
correct output: [1,3,4]

```
void deleteNode(ListNode* node) {
    ListNode* next = node->next;
    *node = *(node->next);
    delete next;
}
```

Above is a valid solution. 
However, I am thinking it shouldn't be correct.

Reason:
In the 2nd line of the function, you are copying the value/content of the whole node.
So you end up copying the int value, as well as the address of the next node (i.e. the next node pointer).

However, in the 3rd and final line of the function, you end up deleting next (which is equivalent to node->next).

When you do enough allocations in the future, would this not cause overwrite issues? 
From my understanding, the next pointer now holds the address space of something that was just deleted.

If I am wrong in my understanding, I'd really appreciate someone correcting me.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly learn how to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's investigate the function step by step:

```
ListNode* next = node->next;
```

Here you copy given node's `next` into a temporary pointer, so far so good. for example if you had `{1, 2, 3, 4}` and gave second node to this function now `next` is 3 and it's third item.

```
 *node = *(node->next);
```

Copy content of next of given node into node, as you mentioned this will also copy it's next to it. continuing given example now you have `{1, 3, 3, 4}` which both 3s (second and third item's next are 4 (forth item)).

```
delete next;
```

Delete next. Now, given past example what you are doing here is deleting the second 3 (third item). and your result will be `{1, 3, 4}`.

This method will not delete the exact given node (I mean it's not deleting given pointer) but it copy it's next into it then delete the next and it's works as intended.

[image]

Comment: That's incorrect. `*node = *(node->next);` only copies the values of the memory pointed to, but `node` still points to the same memory location, and accessing it again (to list the elements) is UB. We've also just leaked the 3rd item.

Comment: @aybassiouny No! you copied content of third item into second and delete third item. where is the UB or leak??

Comment: You copied content of third item into second and deleted *second* item.

Comment: @aybassiouny No I delete the third Item, `next` is the next of the given item. which means if you give the second to function `next` will be third item. read it again please.

Comment: @HMD, THANK YOU!!!!! your diagram helped so much!!! I made such a rookie mistake, I should have drawn a diagram like you (which I believe is the main problem, had a drawn the diagram, I wouldn't have been so hopselessly confused). You are correct. I was thinking that maybe aybassiouny was correct, but I agree that your solution is correct. Thank you both!

Comment: @GrayKim you are welcome, be careful with pointers, they can be very confusing at the start.

Comment: @HMD I think a better advice might be to not get cocky with pointers. For a while, I was thinking "Pointers? Address space to a pointer holding the value; ez pz lemonsqueezy"... until this happens lol

Answer (score 0):

That's correct, dereferencing the memory location `node` used to point to is Undefined Behavior. It's worth pointing out that `delete` does not really zero the memory, because that's extra work and C++ is all about not doing anything it's not explicitly asked to do.

```
int* x = new int;
*x = 5;
int* y = x;
delete x;
std::cout << *y << std::endl; // This outputs 5 on my machine (on release config)
```

What rather happens is that the memory manager in the OS marks those locations as free and they *might* get occupied later. Maybe not. Until this memory gets overwritten, it would return the correct value. But again, this is UB, and no production code should have it.

Keep in mind that *sometimes* the c++ runtime can zero the memory after it gets freed, for example when compiling with debug flags.

Comment: While this scenario and explanation is correct, it's completely irrelevant to the question.  You copied a pointer to another pointer and delete the pointer and now it's UB, in question it first copy *content* of pointer to another pointer then delete one of them (two different pointers) and it's not your case.

Comment: My thought process is in alignment with aybassiouny. However, i am not sure who is correct, him or HMD. lol. I will look at both of your answers carefully and vote for the solution I think is correct. thank you both for your efforts! I'm so confooozed!!